# Can I determine the mode of constant data?

Tags: probability-theory

I know that " 1 2 3 4 5 6 " doesn't have any mode.
But there is other problem.
Does " 1 1 1 1 1 1 " have mode 1 or any mode?

I guessed that it will have mode 1, but there are some netizens who tells me there isn't any mode.

Comment: How about  "1 2 2 3 4 4"? What will its mode be?

Comment: You simply add the exact definition of "mode" to your question, and even if you still can't see the answer, others may.

Comment: I'm legitimately confused that anyone would say the mode of the data $1,1,1,1,1,1$ is not $1.$ I don't think there's any ambiguity there... one is clearly the most frequently occurring value in the sample. As for your first example $1,2,3,4,5,6$ it's a little less clear. By the definition I use, this sample has $6$ modes... $1,2,3,4,5$ and $6$ since they are all tied for "the most frequent". As Mohammad alluded to, it is natural to say a sample like $1,2,2,3,4,4$ has two modes, $2$ and $4.$

Comment: Mohammad // There are 2 modes, '2' and '4'.
      Pf. Vector // Thanks for your advise.
      darkgreen // I can understand that the definition of mode can be varied, but isn't there a well-using definition of mode?

--OK, I understood what I have to say.
I uses the definition of mode as 'the most variate in a data', but I feel it has ambiguity. 'the most' will be obvious if there are other variates to compare. So I guessed the mode will be 1.
But here(I'm living in South Korea), 'there is no mode' seems correct answer. So it is my question : Can I accept the concept without refutation?